# ¿Como contar determinados valores dentro de un POST?

Tags: php, html

Estoy enviando un conjunto de archivos a traves de POST, lo que necesito es contar con PHP cuantas imagenes hay dentro de ese POST, lo que se envia es de este tipo:

```
file[]: 554f2b2f7d00f90fa24cfcd4f1a1de19.jpg
file[]: 75554a79325ebd3342c27c7bb7d3ffc4.txt
file[]: 17623f055ea101e2da38b1e0a33ee01c.png
file[]: ac40d5b9ac52f8d7c751694e460cd087.png
```

Comment: Has probado "$numero_variables = count($_POST);", o hay más POST que no son archivos?

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, pero lo que yo necesito es saber cuantas son imagenes, ese codigo que comentas me devuelve todo el contenido del post y no todas son imagenes. Espero haberme podido explicar. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para saber cuantos POST se han hecho sería:

```
$numero_archivos = count($_POST);
echo $numero_archivos;
```

Para saber cuantos POST en una misma ubicación:

```
$archivos = $_POST['file'];
$num_archivos =  count($archivos);
echo $num_archivos;
```

> Este ultimo se debe a que en una posición al poderse guardar más de un
>   valor en un espacio de POST la variable $archivos se declara como un
>   array.

Cuenta solo archivos que son imagenes(solo png y jpg):

```
<?php

$contador=0;
$ficheros = $_POST['file'];

foreach($ficheros as $fichero){
  $pos_punto = strpos($fichero, ".");
  $formato = substr($fichero, $pos_punto+1);
  if($formato=="png"||$formato=="jpg"){
    contador++;
  }
}

echo "Hay ".$contador." archivos de imagenes.";

?>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, pero lo que yo necesito es saber cuantas son imagenes, ese codigo que comentas me devuelve todo el contenido del post y no todas son imagenes. Espero haberme podido explicar. Gracias!

Comment: Es un poco más enrevesado pero se puede hacer, unas preguntas antes de nada, el input admite más archivos que solo imagenes? y quieres que cuente determinados?(ejemplo:que solo lea png y jpg)

Comment: Sisi, asi tal vual, el input admite cualquier tipo de archivo, pero yo necesito contar las que son imagenes. Gracias!!

Comment: @Patricio He actualizado la respuesta y añadi abajo lo que pedías aunque lo hice pensando en solo archivos png y jpg, si quieres añadir más archivos puedes. Oh y si quieres poner archivos en que en el nombre haya más de un punto también se puede(lo puedo añadir encantado), y ten cuidado con archivos que el formato este en mayuscula. Buena suerte!

Comment: Gracias!!, en un momento lo prueboo!!. Muchas gracias!